# How to display an array in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays

This is the code I currently have:

```
<?php
 echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=stackoverflow&format=ARRAY");
?>
```

It is displaying this on my page:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [idx] => 0
        [title] => Stack Overflow
        [description] => A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.
        [url] => http://stackoverflow.com/
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [idx] => 1
        [title] => Stack Overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
        [description] => Stack Overflow website logo.png &middot; Stack Overflow.png. Screenshot of Stack Overflow as of December 2011. Web address &middot; stackoverflow.com. Commercial? Yes.
        [url] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
    )
)
```

What do I need to change to have it displayed like this instead?

```
1.  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>
A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.

2.  <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow">Stack Overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a>
Stack Overflow website logo.png &middot; Stack Overflow.png. Screenshot of Stack Overflow as of December 2011. Web address &middot; stackoverflow.com. Commercial? Yes.
```

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a third-party API. What does their documentation say?

Comment: It seems output of print_r. Is it right or it's your print_r ?

Comment: `$result = file_get_contents(.....); foreach($result as $value) { do something with $value }`

Comment: @hd1 I've probably tried 100 different things and nothing seems to work.  I'm guessing that I simply don't understand how to pull arrays from pages and actually use their data.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario This isn't a third party API, it's an older PHP script that I got awhile back and it doesn't look like the original author is active anymore.

Comment: @EscalateInternet - You cannot use *variables* from a remote application. That's not how computers or the WWW work. You have to dump data to a stream and them parse data back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) function is a debug helper. It isn't intended as serialisation format:

- There aren't built-in parsers (and it isn't trivial to write a *robust* one)
- It can cause data loss, e.g.:

  ```
  $data = array(true, 1, false, 0, '');
  print_r($data);

  Array
  (
      [0] => 1
      [1] => 1
      [2] => 
      [3] => 0
      [4] => 
  )
  ```

You have this in the URL:

```
format=ARRAY
```

Just look at whatever place you use `$_GET['format']`. You'll possibly have more useful formats to choose from. If you don't, it'll be trivial to implement a sensible format, e.g. [JSON](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: It looks like there is an option for JSON.  Would posting that output make it easier?  It doesn't matter to me which I use...

Comment: If you have to ask whether calling `json_decode()` is easier than writing a custom parser for a bogus pseudo-format, it means that I've failed to properly explain the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**foreach**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) control statement of PHP in order to achieve this, and here it goes:

Say that the **`$array`** is the resultant of **file_get_contents** and supposing that it holds the result to be displayed.

```
    <?php foreach($array as $arr){?>
     <a href="<?php echo $arr['url'];?>"><?php echo $arr['title'];?></a>
     <?php echo $arr['description']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Hope this helps you....

Comment: I got this error with that code:  `[07-Aug-2014 02:01:31 America/Chicago] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/site/public_html/folder/folder/index.php`